# Sata showing as ACASI SCSI drive

Tags: sata, usb-3, scsi

I have a western digital blue 500gb 2.5inch in an external USB 3 case. it's showing as an ACASI SCSI drive in win 10 disk management (all other drives are showing as sata).
All is fine when using it in the pc but plugging it into the TV, it isn't recognised and won't allow access to files.
Any thoughts on how to reset it as a Sata drive

Answer (score 3):

Please do more research before posting questions;

### ***TL;DR***

1, Your HDD is definitely a SATA drive, impossible to be anything else. It is shown as SCSI because it is equipped with a SCSI chip.

2, Your TV can't recognize your HDD is probably because your HDD is formatted to NTFS, and your TV can't read NTFS; Try formatting your HDD FAT32 and see if it solves your problem.

---

### ***Answer Body***

External HDDs ([Hard Disk Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)) are mobile (laptop) SATA ([Serial Advanced Technology Attachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA)) HDDs equipped with a small a SCSI ([Small Computer System Interface](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiNvLKJk53uAhVRPHAKHSd2BXUQmhMwKnoECEAQAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSCSI&usg=AOvVaw0iWTy73lR-B7epFyGaoWlN)) USB ([Universal Data Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)) converter chip that [bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_converter) the (SATA) interface to [Fibre Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel) (FC) which connects the HDD to a USB port, they are enclosed in an [external disk enclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_enclosure);

2.5 inch HDDs are laptop HDDs, 3.5 inch HDDs are desktop HDDs; Nowadays external HDDs are usually equipped with [USB 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0) chips;
This is the USB convertor chip in a Seagate Expansion 2TB 2.5 inch external HDD after I have made the HDD itself internal, though this is Seagate, not Western Digital, I once bought several WD external disks and opened the enclosures after they stopped working properly, and they are using the same design:

[image]

[image]

The above is a SAS-SCSI-FC ([Serial Attached SCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI)-Small Computer System Interface-[Fibre Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FATA_(hard_disk_drive)))converter chip, it bridges standard 2.5 inch laptop SATA HDD to USB 3.0 interface and connects the HDD to USB 3.0 port.

This is the HDD itself:

[image]

[image]

The disk uses standard SATA connector, the 15 pin segment provides power to the HDD, the 7 pin segment allows data transfer. When external, the SATA connector is connected to the big side of the chip, the chip is in turn connected to the computer's USB 3.0 port via a USB 3.0 cable, the port in turn is connected to the motherboard.

The USB 3.0 cable splits the cable into power lines and data lines, which are connected to the respective segments of the SATA connector. When internal, the 15 pin segment of the SATA connector on the disk is connected to a SATA power cable extended from the PSU (Power Supply Unit), the 7 pin part is connected to the motherboard via a SATA data cable.

You external HDD is not shown as a SATA drive because it isn't directly connected to the SATA port on the motherboard via a SATA data cable. Instead it is connected to the computer through the USB converter, the converter controls data read/write to the HDD itself on behalf of the HDD, the computer isn't directly dealing with the HDD, instead it deals with the chip, so the disk isn't shown as a SATA disk.

To reset it as a SATA drive is impossible, because it already is a SATA drive, resetting it doesn't make any sense. If you want to make the HDD be shown as a SATA drive in your computer, you can't make it happen while the HDD is inside the enclosure; You have to open the enclosure, pull off the converter chip, and connect the HDD directly to the computer to make it internal.

In this way it will be shown as a SATA drive. But I recommend against doing it, as you aren't an expert and external HDD's warranty will be over if the case is opened.

And in this way you can't connect the HDD to the TV, you can't connect the HDD to the TV internally. TVs don't support it, you can only connect the HDDs via USB through the convertor...

"Smart" TVs and "Smart" phones, to put it bluntly, are crappy computers with poor performance designed specifically for the innocent populace to rip huge money off them.

Your smart TV can't recognize your HDD is probably because it can't read NTFS filesystem, and your HDD is formatted NTFS.

NTFS ([New Technology File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)) is the most modern file system. Windows uses NTFS for its system drive and, by default, for most non-removable drives. FAT32 ([File Allocation Table 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32)) is an older file system that’s not as efficient as NTFS and doesn’t support as big a feature set, but does offer greater compatibility with other operating systems.

### ***NT File System (NTFS)***

> NTFS is the modern file system Windows likes to use by default. When
> you install Windows, it formats your system drive with the NTFS file
> system. NTFS has file size and partition size limits that are so
> theoretically huge you won’t run up against them. NTFS first appeared
> in consumer versions of Windows with Windows XP, though it originally
> debuted with Windows NT. NTFS is packed with modern features which are
> not available on FAT32 and exFAT. NTFS supports file permissions for
> security, a change journal that can help quickly recover errors if
> your computer crashes, shadow copies for backups, encryption, disk
> quota limits, hard links, and various other features. Compatibility :
> Works with all versions of Windows, but read-only with Mac by default,
> and may be read-only by default with some Linux distributions.
> Limitations : No realistic file-size or partition size limits. Ideal
> Usage : Use it for your Windows system drive and other internal drives
> that will just be used with Windows.

### ***File Allocation Table 32 (FAT32)***

> FAT32 is the oldest of the three file systems available to Windows. It
> was introduced all the way back in Windows 95 to replace the older
> FAT16 file system used in MS-DOS and Windows 3. Individual files on a
> FAT32 drive can’t be over 4 GB in size—that’s the maximum. A FAT32
> partition must also be less than 8 TB, which admittedly is less of a
> limitation unless you’re using super-high-capacity drives. Modern
> versions of Windows can no longer be installed to a drive formatted
> with FAT32; they must be installed to drives formatted with NTFS.
> Compatibility : Works with all versions of Windows, Mac, Linux, game
> consoles, and practically anything with a USB port. Limitations : 4 GB
> maximum file size, 8 TB maximum partition size. Ideal Usage : Use it
> on removable drives where you need maximum compatibility with the
> widest range of devices, assuming you don’t have any files 4 GB or
> larger in size.

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-fat32-exfat-ntfs-file-system/#:%7E:text=FAT32%20is%20an%20older%20file,nearly%20as%20widespread%20as%20FAT32.)

Your TV can't recognize your disk is most likely because it isn't compatible with NTFS, and it is very likely it is compatible with FAT32. You should format the drive to FAT32 and see if the smart TV can recognize it.
(And it definitely isn't because your external HDD is SCSI HDD instead of SATA...)

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head - how the drive is detected is a red herring and the issue is probably NTFS filesystem. If I may suggest something, your answer contains a lot of information that, while interesting for geeks, is not exactly necessary for understanding and solving this problem. Most visitors just want to get their issue sorted out, we don't need to turn them into experts. Maybe you could add a short "tl;dr" summary at the beginning?

Comment: Please do more research before posting questions;

Answer (score 0):

Interesting replies.
The hdd is an old laptop drive in an aftermarket case. Was working fine with my pc and tv until i tried to use it in the TV and got the device not supported message, it then stopped being visible in explorer on the pc.
Basically i have retired the drive as it is nearly 5 years old and in regular use. Was hoping for a simple fix but it turns out its easier to buy a new drive

Answer (score 0):

Answer is correct. Old post, I know, but I found it while looking for something else and thought some extra info might help anyone that lands here for the same reason as OP.

The other variables can be the: brand of TV, model of TV and the size of the drive if you're using it for **PVR**. I would check your user manual, or call the manufacturer's help desk first.
I have a 1 year old Kogan TV. (Never again, but it was meant to be a temp)
Pretty much **any FAT32 size is ok for viewing files**, but it **only takes a 32G or less FAT32, when using the PVR feature.** Which was really annoying, as it wasn't stated in the user manual, and I had already purchased a 64G thumb drive for the PVR. Customer support let me know after the 3rd call.

Popping it back and forth between TV and PC isn't good either, (if using for PVR), as most smart TV's try to format the drive to FAT32 immediately, if it's the first time that you have used that feature, while others may ask "drive cannot be read, would you like to format? Yes/No. So popping into the TV and it already begins to format or reformat, before you remove it, will leave you in a world of pain if you have files already on there. If not, just reformatting it back to NTFS on your PC (again you will lose all data) will allow it to work on your PC again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124807)